# Using PHP to display items on page

Tags: php, html, format

I have a document called subjects.txt in the following format:

> DateCreated,Subject,Link
>
> 18.10.2015,"Math",http: //address.html
>
> 17.10.2015,"English",http: //address.html
>
> 18.10.2015,"English",http: //address.html
>
> 19.10.2015,"Science",http: //address.html
>
> 17.10.2015,"Math",http: //address.html

The file contains URLs of sites created based on a school subject. There can be more than one site for a subject.

The goal is to use PHP to open, read, and display the contents of the file in the following format:

> Math
>
> ```
>    Link 1
>    Link 2
> ```
>
> English
>
> ```
>    Link 1
>    Link 2
> ```
>
> Science (because there's only one link, the name of the subject is the
>   link)

So far I've been able to open and read the file:

```
$file = "./subjects.txt";
$subjects = file_get_contents($file);
```

I'm having trouble trying to determine how to go about writing the file in specified format.

I've tried using explode to separate the elements with "," - however I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: It would be easier if you stored the data in a database, is that option available?

Comment: @chris85 unfortunately that option is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another version

```
<?php 
$file = "./subjects.txt";
$h = fopen($file, "r");
if($h !== false) {
    $subjects = [];
    $data = [];
    while(!feof($h)) {
        if($line = trim(fgets($h))) {
            $line = explode(",", $line);
            if(!in_array("DateCreated",$line)) {
                array_push($subjects, $line);
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose($h);

    foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
        if(!isset($data[$subject[1]])) {
            $data[$subject[1]] = [];
        }
        $data[$subject[1]][] = $subject[2];
    }

    foreach ($data as $subject => $links) {
        if(count($links) == 1) {
            echo "<p><a href=" . $links[0]. ">$subject</a></p>\n";
        } else {
            $i = 1;
            echo "<p>$subject</p>\n";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"$link\">link$i</a></li>\n";
                $i++;
            }
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Could it be tweaked so that when the URLs are displayed, they are hyperlinks that say "link 1" "link 2" etc. instead of displaying the actual url?

Comment: For the case where theres only 1 link for a subject, the subject name should be the link -- would that just require an if statement within the foreach?

Comment: Sorry i didn't catch it in an original question - please see another update, good luck!

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your input file looks to be in [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV) format. PHP has a built-in [`fgetcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function designed to make reading CSV data from a file easy.

```
<?php
$file = './subjects.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');

if ($fh === false) {
    die("Can not read {$file}");
}

$data = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
    if ($row[0] === 'DateCreated') {
        // Ignore the column header row
        continue;
    }
    list($date, $subject, $link) = $row;
    if (!isset($data[$subject])) {
        $data[$subject] = array();
    }
    $data[$subject][] = $link;
}
fclose($fh);

foreach ($data as $subject => $links) {
    // TODO: output each subject here
}
```

Comment: I know my example has a comma in it,  but what If we were dealing with ";" or "|"  for example

Comment: The third argument to `fgetcsv` is the delimiter character (`','` in the example above).

Comment: So the third argument can be changed to whichever character correct?

Comment: The delimiter character can be set to any single character which indicates the end of one value in the row and the start of the next. Tab (`"\t"`), semicolon (`';'`) and pipe (`'|'`) delimited files are nearly as common as commas and can be parsed using the same technique.

Comment: @JustAskingThings upvoting and/or accepting the answer is a great way to show appreciation. ;)

Comment: OP can't upvote yet. Using value as array key was a good approach though, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem using file_get_contents() is that retrieves all the file contents into $subjects.

You have to use a different approach. For example `fgets()`:

```
$fp = fopen("./subjects.txt", "r");

if ($fp){
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false){
        // So here you can treat each line individually.
        // You can use explode (";", $line) for example if the line is not empty  
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Using fgets() will allow you to parse each of the file's lines individually.

Answer (score 0):

As stated doing this with a database would be much easier probably 3 lines of code. Here's one approach you could use though.

```
$data = '18.10.2015,"Math",http: //address.html

17.10.2015,"English",http: //address1.html

18.10.2015,"English",http: //address2.html

19.10.2015,"Science",http: //address3.html

17.10.2015,"Math",http: //address4.html';
preg_match_all('~^(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?)$~m', $data, $fields);
array_multisort($fields[2], SORT_STRING, $fields[1], $fields[3]);
$lastcat = '';
foreach($fields[2] as $key => $cat) {
    if($cat != $lastcat) {
        echo $cat . "\n";
    }
    $lastcat = $cat;
    echo $fields[3][$key] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
English
http: //address1.html
http: //address2.html
Math
http: //address4.html
http: //address.html
Science
http: //address3.html
```

The [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is how the categories are grouped.

Here's a regex101 demo of what that regex is doing. https://regex101.com/r/wN3nB2/1

Update for single record check (only ran 1 test on it):

```
$data = '18.10.2015,"Math",http: //address.html

17.10.2015,"English",http: //address1.html

18.10.2015,"English",http: //address2.html

19.10.2015,"Science",http: //address3.html

17.10.2015,"Math",http: //address4.html';
preg_match_all('~^(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?)$~m', $data, $fields);
array_multisort($fields[2], SORT_STRING, $fields[1], $fields[3]);
$lastcat = '';
foreach($fields[2] as $key => $cat) {
    if((empty($fields[2][($key +1)]) && $cat != $lastcat)|| ($cat != $lastcat && !empty($fields[2][($key +1)]) && $fields[2][($key +1)] != $cat)) {
        //single record
        echo $cat . $fields[3][$key] . "\n";
    } else {
        if($cat != $lastcat) {
            echo $cat . "\n";
        }
        $lastcat = $cat;
        echo $fields[3][$key] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output seems to be displaying the dates created - would $fields[3] fix this?

Comment: Oh, opps, yup that would be correct. Updated answer as well.

Comment: For the Science case; because there is only one link, the subject name should be a hyperlink to the site. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: It'd just take an extra conditional. Updated for that case as well.

Comment: Instead of $data = '.....' can I use: $file = './subjects.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'r'); then set $fh to $data? Also, Link 1 should just be a hyperlink to the actual URL, what steps would that require?

Comment: $data can be any string. The string just needs to be in the format you displayed above. You should be able to convert a string to a link.. You shouldn't have the space between `:` and `//`.

Comment: Just having issues setting the new data to the .txt file

Comment: Okay, not sure what you are doing there because question doesn't go into that but once you get that working be sure to accept one of the answers provided here.

Comment: Im trying to get $data to point to the actual text file instead of the quotes. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: $data = file_get_contents('location');

Comment: Just ran everything and the output is completely different: "English http: //address.html http: //address.html Math http: //address.html http: //address.html Sciencehttp: //address.html" all showing on one line

Comment: Are you in a browser or command line? If browser change `\n` to `<br>`.

Comment: That did the trick! How would I got about hyperlinking the sites for each subject? I.e. Underneath English it would be Page 1 (with a link to the site) then underneath that would Page 2(with a link to that site)? P.s. thanks for the prompt replies!

Comment: So just for `math` and `english` right? Because science already linked...Is so the `echo $cat` is the single categories so make the category links there.

Comment: Sample.txt has a lot more than 5 elements in it - its basically a database of multiple sites. The format I supplied above was just an example. Does this help give better context as to what I'm explaining?

Comment: Modify the regex and it should work as expected. Of course you'll have to modify the keys so you use the right fields.